# What's correct transformation for Lambert Conformal Conic for Wyoming?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, united-states

I am a new to QGIS. I have loaded QGIS 1.8 (Lisboa) and practicing with a number of maps for portions of the state of Wyoming. My maps are mostly in UTM 12N NAD 27 & NAD 83 some are in decimal degrees and one is Lambert Conformal Conic NAD 83 with false Easting and False Northing offsets.

There is no problem handling the maps in UTM 12N NAD 83 to overlay on those in UTM 12 NAD 27. But I cannot find a CSR Transformation for the Lambert Conformal Conic for Wyoming. The list contains practically all the states but not Wyoming.

Am I looking in the wrong place, or is it simply not there?

Answer (score 2):

After more research, I finally found the answer.
The metadata for Wyoming maps in Lambert Conformal Conic NAD 83 projection provide 3 parallels (latitudes) see below. But the CRS projection string showing in qgis shows only lat_1 and lat_0. Missing in this string is lat_2=45.
the CRS for this Wyoming Lambert Conformal Conic NAD 83 projection should be:

**+proj=lcc +lat_1=41 +lat_2=45 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-107.5 +k_0=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs**

here is the metadata for the map projection:

PROJCS["WyLam",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",200000.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",107.5],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",41.0],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",45.0],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",41.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Answer (score 0):

Downloading some sample data from http://wgfd.wyo.gov/web2011/wildlife-1000820.aspx, I get the following Custom CRS proj string:

> +proj=lcc +lat_1=41 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-107.5 +k_0=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

Maybe that works with your data too.